# combining two dictionaries after removing some componetnts

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries as follows.

```
  A=  {'photos': {'page': 1,
  'pages': 2,
  'perpage': 250,
  'photo': [{'accuracy': '16',
    'context': 0,
    'datetaken': '2013-05-03 13:47:02',
    'datetakengranularity': '0',
    'datetakenunknown': '0',
    'farm': 5,
    'geo_is_contact': 0,
    'geo_is_family': 0,
    'geo_is_friend': 0,
    'geo_is_public': 1,
    'id': '26970758199',
    'isfamily': 0,
    'isfriend': 0,
    'ispublic': 1,
    'latitude': '5.944650',
    'longitude': '80.459766',
    'owner': '61943224@N04',
    'place_id': 'kLamY9hTU7IVDlGv',
    'secret': '1383a29a3b',
    'server': '4563',
    'title': 'Mirissa - Ask your Local Tour Dog',
    'woeid': '2182931'},
   {'accuracy': '14',
    'context': 0,
    'datetaken': '2017-09-28 18:13:17',
    'datetakengranularity': 0,
    'datetakenunknown': '1',
    'farm': 5,
    'geo_is_contact': 0,
    'geo_is_family': 0,
    'geo_is_friend': 0,
    'geo_is_public': 1,
    'id': '37343882352',
    'isfamily': 0,
    'isfriend': 0,
    'ispublic': 1,
    'latitude': '5.930026',
    'longitude': '80.405502',
    'owner': '7415626@N04',
    'place_id': 'J1bv5NZTU70_mRm8',
    'secret': 'c7135b74d2',
    'server': '4335',
    'title': 'Blue whale tail',
    'woeid': '2179328'}],
  'total': '2'},
 'stat': 'ok'}
```

and the second dictonary  as follows:

```
    B={'photos': {'page': 2,
      'pages': 2,
      'perpage': 250,
      'photo': [{'accuracy': '12',
        'context': 0,
        'datetaken': '2013-02-19 12:02:57',
        'datetakengranularity': '0',
        'datetakenunknown': 0,
        'farm': 9,
        'geo_is_contact': 0,
        'geo_is_family': 0,
        'geo_is_friend': 0,
        'geo_is_public': 1,
        'id': '8516011398',
        'isfamily': 0,
        'isfriend': 0,
        'ispublic': 1,
        'latitude': '5.935533',
        'longitude': '80.446357',
        'owner': '22857808@N03',
        'place_id': 'kLamY9hTU7IVDlGv',
        'secret': 'e6c6b8548c',
        'server': '8112',
        'title': 'Whale & Dolphin Watching Mirissa',
        'woeid': '2182931'},
       {'accuracy': '12',
        'context': 0,
        'datetaken': '2013-02-19 11:13:47',
        'datetakengranularity': '0',
        'datetakenunknown': 0,
        'farm': 9,
        'geo_is_contact': 0,
        'geo_is_family': 0,
        'geo_is_friend': 0,
        'geo_is_public': 1,
        'id': '8514896103',
        'isfamily': 0,
        'isfriend': 0,
        'ispublic': 1,
        'latitude': '5.935533',
        'longitude': '80.446357',
        'owner': '22857808@N03',
        'place_id': 'kLamY9hTU7IVDlGv',
        'secret': '17df7f97e7',
        'server': '8375',
        'title': 'Whale & Dolphin Watching Mirissa',
        'woeid': '2182931'}],
  'total': '2'},
 'stat': 'ok'}
```

I want to merge this dictonaries together after removing the

```
{'photos': {'page': '',
      'pages': '',
      'perpage': '',
```

and removing the last section of each of A and B dictionaries,

```
  'total': ''},
 'stat': ''}
```

sections in both A and B. So my final output should be like this,

```
C='photo': [{'accuracy': '16',
        'context': 0,
        'datetaken': '2013-05-03 13:47:02',
        'datetakengranularity': '0',
        'datetakenunknown': '0',
        'farm': 5,
        'geo_is_contact': 0,
        'geo_is_family': 0,
        'geo_is_friend': 0,
        'geo_is_public': 1,
        'id': '26970758199',
        'isfamily': 0,
        'isfriend': 0,
        'ispublic': 1,
        'latitude': '5.944650',
        'longitude': '80.459766',
        'owner': '61943224@N04',
        'place_id': 'kLamY9hTU7IVDlGv',
        'secret': '1383a29a3b',
        'server': '4563',
        'title': 'Mirissa - Ask your Local Tour Dog',
        'woeid': '2182931'},
       {'accuracy': '14',
        'context': 0,
        'datetaken': '2017-09-28 18:13:17',
        'datetakengranularity': 0,
        'datetakenunknown': '1',
        'farm': 5,
        'geo_is_contact': 0,
        'geo_is_family': 0,
        'geo_is_friend': 0,
        'geo_is_public': 1,
        'id': '37343882352',
        'isfamily': 0,
        'isfriend': 0,
        'ispublic': 1,
        'latitude': '5.930026',
        'longitude': '80.405502',
        'owner': '7415626@N04',
        'place_id': 'J1bv5NZTU70_mRm8',
        'secret': 'c7135b74d2',
        'server': '4335',
        'title': 'Blue whale tail',
        'woeid': '2179328'},
       {'accuracy': '12',
        'context': 0,
        'datetaken': '2013-02-19 12:02:57',
        'datetakengranularity': '0',
        'datetakenunknown': 0,
        'farm': 9,
        'geo_is_contact': 0,
        'geo_is_family': 0,
        'geo_is_friend': 0,
        'geo_is_public': 1,
        'id': '8516011398',
        'isfamily': 0,
        'isfriend': 0,
        'ispublic': 1,
        'latitude': '5.935533',
        'longitude': '80.446357',
        'owner': '22857808@N03',
        'place_id': 'kLamY9hTU7IVDlGv',
        'secret': 'e6c6b8548c',
        'server': '8112',
        'title': 'Whale & Dolphin Watching Mirissa',
        'woeid': '2182931'},     
        {'accuracy': '12',
        'context': 0,
        'datetaken': '2013-02-19 11:13:47',
        'datetakengranularity': '0',
        'datetakenunknown': 0,
        'farm': 9,
        'geo_is_contact': 0,
        'geo_is_family': 0,
        'geo_is_friend': 0,
        'geo_is_public': 1,
        'id': '8514896103',
        'isfamily': 0,
        'isfriend': 0,
        'ispublic': 1,
        'latitude': '5.935533',
        'longitude': '80.446357',
        'owner': '22857808@N03',
        'place_id': 'kLamY9hTU7IVDlGv',
        'secret': '17df7f97e7',
        'server': '8375',
        'title': 'Whale & Dolphin Watching Mirissa',
        'woeid': '2182931'}]
```

I have tried several dictionaries merging methods, and none of those yield results, I'm bit new to python. I would be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
C = A['photos']['photo']
C.extend(B['photos']['photo'])
D = {'photo': C}
print(D)
```

Basically You need item `photo` from both the dictionaries. Since this Item's value is a list, we can create a new list called C with one list and extend the other list.

Reference:- [Python List extend()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:-

```
def mergedict(A,B):
    r1 = []
    k = {}
    for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(A.items(), B.items()):
        if k=='photos':
            r1.append(A[k]['photo'])
        elif k2=='photos':
            r1.append(B[k2]['photo'])
    k['photos']=r1[0]
    return k

C=mergedict(A,B)
print(C)
```